# Problem to save data from ComboBox in VB6

Tags: sql, sql-server, combobox, vb6

I've a `ComboBox` but the problem is that when I try to save the value selected, 'cause I load the `ComboBox` with values of `SQLServer` and the applications shows me the next error:

> [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver][SQL Server]Invalid column name 'celular'.

I load the `ComboBox` with values of `SQL`:

```vb
Private Sub Form_Load()
   Set rs = New Recordset
   rs.CursorLocation = adUseServer

   Call IniciarConexion

   CargaIDTipoNumero
End Sub

Private Sub CargaIDTipoNumero()
    cmbAddExample(indice).Clear
    rs.Open "SELECT tipo FROM tipo_Numero", cnn, adOpenDynamic, adLockOptimistic
    Do While rs.EOF = False
        cmbAddExample(indice).AddItem rs!tipo
        rs.MoveNext
    Loop
    rs.Close
End Sub

Private Sub IniciarConexion()
    Set cnn = New ADODB.Connection
    With cnn
        .CursorLocation = adUseClient
        .Open "PROVIDER=MSDASQL;driver={SQL Server};server=server;uid=uid;pwd=pwd;database=database;"
    End With
End Sub
```

The table where saves the values of `ComboBox`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE ejTres(
    combo int
)
```

The table with I load the `ComboBox`:

```sql
CREATE TABLE tipo_Numero(
    idTipo INT IDENTITY (1,1) NOT NULL, 
    tipo VARCHAR (10) NOT NULL, 
    CONSTRAINT pk_tipo PRIMARY KEY(idTipo)
)

INSERT INTO tipo_Numero(tipo)
VALUES('celular'), ('fijo')
```

And the `Button` where I save the values:

```vb
Private Sub btnGuardar_Click()
Dim i As Integer
Dim CM As ADODB.Command

Set CM = New ADODB.Command
Set CM.ActiveConnection = cnn
    CM.CommandType = adCmdText
    CM.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ejTres (combo) VALUES (?)"
    CM.Parameters.Append CM.CreateParameter("@combo", adInteger, , , cmbAddExample(i))
    CM.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
End Sub
```

Comment: You *really* need to parametrise your code before anything. This is open to Injection as it is.

Comment: Print out `sql` before executing it. Then please see https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/11683.

Comment: Yes, but this DB is an example. @Larnu

Comment: A parameterized query will not only avoid the security issue, it will prevent the invalid column name error.

Comment: Any example? @DanGuzman

Comment: It appears you are loading the combo with descriptive strings and then want to save the related identity value to the other table.  Is this an accurate statement?

Comment: Yes, i need save the identity value @BrianMStafford

Comment: As you are loading the combo, you could put the identity value into `ItemData`.  Then during save, reference `ItemData` as you are creating the parameter.

Comment: Any example? @BrianMStafford

Comment: @FranqoBalsamo, [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ado/reference/ado-api/parameters-collection-ado) includes an example.

Comment: I read the documentation but i don't understand how to save the identity value selected in the combobox. This is my problem @DanGuzman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Focusing only on the issue of how to get the Identity value into your table, try something like the following:

```
''as you load the combo, also save the identity value

Do While rs.EOF = False
   cmbAddExample(indice).AddItem rs!tipo
   cmbAddExample(indice).ItemData(cmbAddExample(indice).NewIndex) = rs!idTipo
   rs.MoveNext
Loop


''now retrieve the identity value when creating the parameter

id = cmbAddExample(i).ItemData(cmbAddExample(i).ListIndex)

Set CM = New ADODB.Command
Set CM.ActiveConnection = cnn
CM.CommandType = adCmdText
CM.CommandText = "INSERT INTO ejTres (combo) VALUES (?)"
CM.Parameters.Append CM.CreateParameter("@combo", adInteger, , , id)
CM.Execute , , adExecuteNoRecords
```

Comment: id is a variable?

Comment: Yes.  `id` would be either Integer or Long.  I just broke it out for clarity in what I was trying to show.